# Angular Home Page Component routing issue

Tags: angular, docker, nginx, angular-ui-router

I have 2 components in angular

1. Webpage
2. Registeration Form

The routes should be like

```
localhost:4200 - Home Component
localhost:4200/register - Registeration Component
```

But in router modules nothing can be set on base path

```
  { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: PlayerListComponent },
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'home', pathMatch: 'full' }
```

App component :

```
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Final output :

```
localhost:4200/home - Home Component
localhost:4200/register - Registeration Component
```

How can I set one component on **ROOT** and others as default routing system works. Also if there's a way to deploy it in Nginx with some configuration to set `/home as /`, I am open to that solution as well

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If these routes are completely independent of each other, the correct way to do this is to set the Home Component path blank and remove the redirection object, like this:

```
  { path: '', component: HomeComponent },
  { path: 'register', component: RegisterComponent },
  { path: 'admin', component: PlayerListComponent },
```

Comment: answer incomplete, if home component has children, it would need router as well, right? Please elaborate. btw I applied this, it worked for ROOT, but redirection is broken

Comment: Yes, in this case the home component would need a router-outlet inside it. But if not then you can just leave the Home Component path blank { path: 'home', component: HomeComponent }, and remove the redirect part, right? I will add this option in the answer as well.

Comment: blank path solution worked, update your answer accordingly

Comment: I removed the children part of the answer and left only the blank path solution.